# Handling large data files

Tags: java, architecture

Lets say I have a very big file having data. A parser parses it and keeps the data in the following class:

```
Class Data{
  DataHeader header;
  List<DataLine> lines;
  ... 
}
```

Before persisting this data in the DB, I do some validations and processing on it. And I persist it only if there are no errors in it.

Data file looks like:

```
DATAHEADER|.......
DATALINE|1|....
DATALINE|2|....
... and so on
```

To process this file in a limited JVM memory, it should be processed in batches and also made sure that it is persisted only if it does not have any errors. Appreciate your help on designing the solution.

Comment: Does validation include consistency checks that require access to multiple lines, or only local checks?

Comment: What do you mean "the file should be processed in batches", how would that make it scalable?

Comment: @particia most of the validations are done locally. But at last, few validations are done on the over all data. For example: validating the line count.

Comment: @djna I may be wrong, but I mean to say that this would save out of memory errors.

Comment: @KevindraSingh Update your question with "WHAT" you want to do with an example of the input and output (use real data). Then specify your constraints and validation rules. Then you would get a better answer.

Comment: So you mean that avoiding loading the whole file into memory will allow you process larger files. This is probably true, but is a quite restricted example of the general concept of scalability, hence my confusion.

Comment: "The last few validations are done over all the data" - we need to know what these last few validations are. Simple line count can of course be maintained as we read the file, so no problem, but what else do you need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With big files, you can't always load everything into memory. You sometime have to create a temp table to store the information.

- Read a few lines and store them in a list
- Check if lines, making sure the data is correct
- If it's good, store the line in the temp table in the database
- If it's bad, delete the data in the temp table and stop the process with an error

When the file has been loaded in the temp table

- Do you global check (try to do them in the database, don't fetch everything back in the application)
- If it's good, copy the data from the temp table into the live table. Delete the temp table
- If it's bad, delete the data in the temp table and stop the process with an error